# generate a column of random numbers

Tags: r, sample, recycle, rep

I wanted to generate a column of random numbers in R taking values between 1 and 371, but I get an error I am not able to fix.

here is the code

```
library(readstata13)

#load data sets
data1<- read.dta13("file1.dta", convert.factors = FALSE, select.cols=(c("var1") ))

data2<- read.dta13("file2.dta", convert.factors = FALSE, select.cols=(c("var2") ))

finaldataset <-rbindlist(list(data1, data2),idcol=TRUE)

set.seed(123456789)

finaldataset$lad<-sample(371)
```

this is the error message I get

```
Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 371 items to be assigned to 36137 items of column 'lad'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: `finaldataset$lad <- sample(1:371, length(finaldataset$lad))` ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot load your data and therefore examine it, however, it seems as though you are trying to create a column that is not the same length as the columns in your finaldataset.
Just using sample(371) will only create 371 values, therefore, you will need to specify how many values to create i.e. a size that is the same length as your other data.

Comment: Thank you,  I've actually used another command that specified the number of rows in the dataset by  using  this command  finaldataset$lad <- floor(runif(n=36137, min=1, max=372))
 and it worded weel. However, I was wondering whether there is any workaround without the need to include the exact number of rows.

Comment: Perhaps you could try the line of code in the other comment, however, replace `$lad` with an existing column name e.g. if in `finaldataset` you had a column named `col1`, then use `finaldataset$lad <- sample(1:371, length(finaldataset$col1))`